# Joomla text wrap around intro image

Tags: image, text, joomla, joomla3.0

I am try to get text to wrap around my intro image, I select float image left but it doesn't float left. Does anyone know of this issue and how to fix it?

This is the site: http://www.benidormallyearround.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is generated by the block roksocialbuttons, inserting several Div not possible to apply the CSS rule on the image.
Place the image after the social buttons.

Answer (score 0):

you are asking about this attached image alignment issue right? I little confused..

[image]

Comment: He resolved, moving and removing buttons "roksocialbuttons" social networks. This morning did not look well.